# importing pyshark on windows platform resulting in multiple errors

Tags: windows, pyshark

my python version is 3.7.2
windows version is Windows 7 Ultimate Service pack 1
pyshark version is 0.4.2.2
LXML version is 4.3.2

```
Issue :- "import  pyshark "  alone is resulting me in the  following errors 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ab/RJS2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyshark

 File "C:\Users\ab\PycharmProjects\RJS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyshark\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.live_capture import LiveCapture

File "C:\Users\ab\PycharmProjects\RJS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\live_capture.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyshark.capture.capture import Capture

  File "C:\Users\ab\PycharmProjects\RJS\venv\lib\site-packages\pyshark\capture\capture.py", line 7, in <module>
    import logbook

  File "C:\Users\ab\PycharmProjects\RJS\venv\lib\site-packages\logbook\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .base import (

  File "C:\Users\ab\PycharmProjects\RJS\venv\lib\site-packages\logbook\base.py", line 22, in <module>
    from logbook.helpers import (PY2, cached_property, integer_types, iteritems,

  File "C:\Users\ab\PycharmProjects\RJS\venv\lib\site-packages\logbook\helpers.py", line 60, in <module>
    from http import client as http_client

  File "C:\Users\ab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser

  File "C:\Users\ab\email.py", line 1, in <module>
    import smtplib

  File "C:\Users\ab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.utils'; 'email' is not a package

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: use button `{}` to format code - it will be more readable.

Comment: error shows `No module named 'email.utils';` and I see `C:\Users\ab\email.py`. Did you create file `email.py` ? As for me `smtplib` tries to import standard module `email` but it finds your file `email.py` and it threads it as standard module - but your file is not standard module and it can't find `email.utils` in your file. Rename your file `email.py` into something different - it can't be name of any module because Python will load it instead of expected module.

Comment: Thx a lot, this helped solve the issue